# Python, in a list of lists compare first element of the first list to the first element of the second list

Tags: python, list, subtraction

So I have this:

```
a = [[4, 8], [5, 6, 9, 10], [13]]
```

I want to get the difference (subtraction) between:

```
4 - 5 = a[0][0] - a[1][0]

4 - 6 = a[0][0] - a[1][1]

4 - 9 = a[0][0] - a[1][2]

4 - 10 = a[0][0] - a[1][3]
```

and then move on to the 8:

```
8 - 5 = a[0][1] - a[1][0]

8 - 6 = a[0][1] - a[1][1]

...
```

And so on for all the sub-lists

Any ideas?

EDIT: The other comparisons would look like this:

```
5 - 13 = a[1][0] - a[2][0]

6 - 13 = a[1][1] - a[2][0]

9 - 13 = a[1][2] - a[2][0]

10 - 13 = a[1][3] - a[2][0]
```

And because this is the second to last list, then it stops.

I'm trying to implement the Quine-McCluskey method to minimize logic expressions.

Comment: Can you be more precise on what you mean for "and so on for all the sub-lists"? Do you want the difference between each of 5, 6, 9, 10 with 13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that after finishing `a[0][1] - a[1][x]` you want to continue with `a[0][0] - a[2][0]`, and then eventually also do `a[1][0] - a[2][0]` etc.:

```
result = []
for i, sub_x in enumerate(a[:-1]):
    for sub_y in a[i+1:]:
        for x in sub_x:
            result.append([x - y for y in sub_y])

>>> result
[[-1, -2, -5, -6], [3, 2, -1, -2], [-9], [-5], [-8], [-7], [-4], [-3]]
```

As a list comprehension:

```
[[x - y for y in sub_y]
     for i, sub_x in enumerate(a[:-1]) for sub_y in a[i+1:] for x in sub_x]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I needed. I'm sorry I didn't specify that I wanted to compare the second list to the third one, glad you got it!

Comment: The list comprehension's outer loop iterates a[i+1:] which is different from the outer loop on a[:-1] in the expanded snippet. Is this intentional? Wouldn't that yield different results?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this does what you want,

But I don't know what further iterations you need, since the question is vague.  What do you do with 13?

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> [i[0] - i[1] for i in product([4, 8], [5, 6, 9, 10])]
[-1, -2, -5, -6, 3, 2, -1, -2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    python 3.2
    a=[[4, 8], [5, 6, 9, 10], [13]] 
    [[x-y for x in a[i]for y in a[i+1]]for i in range(len(a)-1)]

    >>>[[-1, -2, -5, -6, 3, 2, -1, -2], [-8, -7, -4, -3]]

   another way:
    for i in range(len(a)-1):
          for v in a[i]:
              y.append(list(v-h for h in a[i+1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you are looking for, this code gives you, for each element in the table, the difference with each element in the next row:

```
output = []
for row_num in range(len(a)-1):
  row_output = []
  output.append(row_output)
  for elt_row in a[row_num]:
    elt_output = []
    row_output.append(elt_output)
    for elt_next_row in a[row_num + 1]:
      elt_output.append(elt_row - elt_next_row)
```